# Jackson \ GSON - Pojo to JSON and vice versa. is file \ serialization mandatory?

Tags: java, json, file, jackson, gson

I'm in need of a JSON - > Pojo - > JSON  transformation.

I looked into the mainstream libraries Jackson and GSON,

Apparently both use:

```
//write converted json data to a file named "file.json"
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("c:\\file.json");

or In\Output Streams..
```

Two things scare me the most when i write new code:

1. I\O (HD specifically)
2. Serialization

I try to avoid both of these as much as I can.

Is there any alternative way to do this?

Comment: What are you talking about? Neither library _requires_ any sort of disk access. That would be preposterous.

Comment: from http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes     "Marshalling back to JSON is similarly straightforward:

mapper.writeValue(new File("user-modified.json"), user);"

Comment: That's just an example. You can read to/write from strings, byte arrays, streams, files, etc.

Comment: As an added bonus, code sample is even wrong by using `FileWriter` without specifying encoding to use. :-D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those libraries DO NOT need to use files to operate, so answering your question: **NO, *file serialization* is not mandatory**. In fact it's not only not mandatory, but it'd be such a pain in the ass to read/write from/to a file each time you need to serialize/deserialize a JSON reponse!

In your example they use a `File` to write and read the JSON in order to *imitate* the usual scenario, which probably includes pass data from/to a web service for example, instead of from/to a `File`...

In fact, for example in Gson, serialization/deserialization is quite straightforward with a simple *Pojo*, just like this:

#### Serialization

```
Pojo pojo = new Pojo();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String pojoJSON = gson.toJson(pojo);
```

#### Deserialization

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Pojo pojo = gson.fromJson(pojoJSON, Pojo.class);
```

I suggest you to take a look at [**Gson documentation**](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide), which is pretty clear and quite short, once you read it you'll understand everything much better...